# Unable to use DYMO 280 Label Printer in my C#.NET Winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net, dymo

I've connected DYMO 280 Label Printer to my pc and trying to print labels from my C# .NET winforms application but I'm facing some errors regarding XML tags.

I'm using DYMO Label v8.0 to create a label templates. Can you pls send me some code examples? Most of the examples I've found are really outdated (from 2011,2011).

I've installed `DYMO.Label` from NuGet packages and moved the `.label` file to my source code.
Below is the code I've tried to print the labels:

```
var label = Label.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\elsis.label");
label.SetObjectText("productCode", productCode);
label.SetObjectText("productPrice", productPrice);
label.Print("DYMO LabelManager 280");
```

```
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element 'TextObject' has invalid child element 'GroupID'. List of possible elements expected: 'HorizontalAlignment'.</ExceptionString></InnerException></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
Exception thrown: 'DYMO.DLS.Runtime.DlsRuntimeException' in DYMO.DLS.Runtime.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'DYMO.DLS.Runtime.DlsRuntimeException' occurred in DYMO.DLS.Runtime.dll
Unable to load label template 'C:\Users\armav\source\repos\Elesis\Elesis\bin\Debug\data\elsis.label'
```

Comment: I don't know about DYMO but it looks like there is an error in the label file. Apparently there is an element `TextObject` containing a child `GroupID` which is invalid for this kind of element. Is there any documentation you could look at?

Comment: Crazy guess: is `data\\elsis.label` perhaps a typo?  - since you have `ElEsis (my emphasis) in the path.

Comment: Yeah the file exists for sure. It's just wrong name. Also I've modified the XML to remove that GorupID but next it gives me another  similar error.

Comment: Hey @ArmanAvetisyan did you found any solution. I have same problem. I can print from label designer software but when i try to print from C# ( using same code as in your question ) it gives me error something like "Unable to load label template"

Comment: I am facing the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but incase anyone else has this problem, I faced this issue with the supplied C# examples.

The reason was the .dll files were not copying into the bin (even though I had the software installed on my PC)
Once I copied the dymo framework DLL's (Interop.DYMOBarcodeLib.dll) it worked.